# Vue / Typescript Generics for interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

What is the correct syntax for allowing anything extending a base type in the following scenario?

```
interface SomeBase {}
interface A extends SomeBase {}
interface B extends SomeBase {}

interface Foo {
 bar: // Can be an array of A or B
}
```

Is it just `bar: SomeBase[]` or is there something like `bar: <? extends SomeBase>`

I don't want to do `bar: A[] | B[]` as there may be a large amount of interfaces and I'd like to avoid explicitly writing them out.

I don't see any documentation offhand for defining it as a variable inside an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar: SomeBase[]` would allow an array of mixed types. If you want a single one, it should be generic.

```
interface SomeBase {}
interface A extends SomeBase {}
interface B extends SomeBase {}

type Foo <T extends SomeBase> = {
 bar: T[];
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'd want a mixed type array. thanks for the clarification!